# How can I bring color in legends in matplotlib?

Tags: dataframe, matplotlib, data-visualization, scatter-plot

I have a following code for specific graph, what I want is those legend to be shown in the graph as
Africa: Skyblue,
Europe: Gold,
Americas: Palegreen

How can I have those colors as my legends?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding `labels = ['Africa', 'Europe', 'America', 'Asia', 'Oceania']` argument in the data.plot.scatter function?

Comment: You are expected to add reproducible code and test data as text, never as image.  Did you consider using seaborn's `sns.scatterplot(...., hue='region', palette={'Africa': 'skyblue', ...})`?